# How do I get zero-padded numbers using brace expansion? {1..30} with 01 02 03 etc

Tags: bash

When doing:

```
for i in {1..30}; do echo $i; grep $i/Aug access.log | sort -u | wc -l; done;
```

the problem is that it goes like this:

```
1/Aug      # should be 01/Aug
2/Aug      # should be 02/Aug
...
```

**How to have `for i in {1..30}` give 01, 02, 03 instead of 1, 2, 3?**

Comment: `printf(1)` is your friend.

Comment: @SatōKatsura I tought about this, but is it a good idea to use that inside a grep and echo? If so, I don't see how to include this inside a grep or echo.

Comment: Downvoter, would you care to explain how I can improve the question?

Comment: @Basj Guessing it has to do with trying to do something in a loop that doesn't require a loop?  You're parsing the file as many times as there are days in August.  You just need one pass...

Comment: @Kusalananda: I need to count the number of unique visitors (IP) each day, so each `sort -u` has to be done for one precise day, that's why I used a loop. Do you really see a solution without loop?

Comment: @Basj Bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `bash` and `zsh`, use `{01..30}`:

```
$ for i in {01..30}; do
      echo $i
      # other code using "$i"
  done
01
02
03
04
05
06
(etc.)
```

In `ksh93`, use `{0..30%02d}`.

In `sh`, or any other POSIX shell, use

```
i=0
while [ "$(( i += 1 ))" -le 30 ]; do
    zi=$( printf '%02d' "$i" )
    echo "$zi"
    # other code using "$zi"
done
```

---

Your variable `i` also needs quoting:

```
for i in {01..30}; do
    echo "$i"
    grep "$i/Aug" access.log | sort -u | wc -l
done
```

Or, alternatively,

```
sed -E -n 's#^.*([0-9][0-9]/Aug).*$#\1#p' access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

or

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9]/Aug' access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

This single pipeline (no loop) would output the dates matching `2-digit-number/Aug` and the number of access log entries matching that date string.

It does so by extracting all occurrence of `[0-9][0-9]/Aug` from the file, sorting them and letting `uniq` count how many times each occurs.

The `grep` variation, although arguably nicer looking than the `sed` command, will give too big numbers *if* the date string occurs multiple times on a line.

Comment: You may need to have `printf "%02d\n" {1..30}` alternative also.

Comment: Also, `seq -w 30`

Comment: @αғsнιη It's an XY problem. The real problem is the parsing of the dates in the access log.

Comment: Why do you have the variable zi?  Why not skip echo and use printf directly?

Comment: @Wildcard Because in the original code in the question, the zero-filled number was being used for something other than just outputting. I will modify to make this clear.

Comment: To match the OP question, the pattern-match alternatives would need to be something like: `([0-2][0-9]|30)/Aug` to exclude `31/Aug`

Comment: @ovirt I dunno. If `31/Aug` or `40/Aug` is in the log file the OP might want to know about it...

Comment: @Kusalananda I was merely adding it for completeness to match the specification of the original question - i.e. `{1..30}` used in combination with a search for `nn/Aug` (but rendered moot given the likely XY nature of the Q)